# How to clone an SVN-managed project in Eclipse without SVN metadata?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, project, subclipse

I have a Java project in Eclipse that is being managed by SVN (Subclipse). I want to make an exact copy of the project, but with a different name, and I don't want to copy over any SVN metadata.

In other words, `myProject` is a working copy of a project hosted in an SVN repo. I want to make `myProject-clone` but such that `myProject-clone` is not also a working copy of the SVN project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go to your folder where the plugin is located copy the plugin and paste into a temp folder. then in that temp folder assuming you are using windows search for *.svn and then select all search results and that will remove all the svn metadata. There might be other ways but that is how I have done it before. One other approach would be to "disconnect" project and select clear all svn metadata then recheck out

Answer (score 1):

Just use the svn export command. Also you could try

copy-item $source -destination $dest -exclude *.svn -recurse

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, *nix or other environment with `rsync` you can pass in the `-C` argument to ignore SVN/CVS metadata:

```
rsync -avC /path/to/working_dir /path/to/copy_dir
```